# Is it possible to access outer local variable in PHP?

Tags: php, scope

Is it possible to access outer local varialbe in a PHP sub-function?

In below code, I want to access variable `$l` in inner function bar. Declaring `$l` as `global $l` in bar doesn't work.

```
function foo()
{
    $l = "xyz";

    function bar()
    {
        echo $l;
    }
    bar();
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could probably use a Closure, to do just that...

**Edit :** took some time to remember the syntax, but here's what it would look like :

```
function foo()
{
    $l = "xyz";
    $bar = function () use ($l)
    {
        var_dump($l);
    };
    $bar();
}
foo();
```

And, running the script, you'd get :

```
$ php temp.php
string(3) "xyz"
```

A couple of note :

- You must put a `;` after the function's declaration !
- You could `use` the variable by reference, with a `&` before it's name : `use (& $l)`

For more informations, as a reference, you can take a look at this page in the manual : [Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Why do you use nested functions at all?

Comment: Who knows ^^ That wasn't the question ^^ ;; with PHP 5.3 and Anonymous functions, it can be pretty useful for Closures ;;; Before PHP 5.3... I've never used any nested function with PHP < 5.3.

Comment: @PascalMARTIN Importantly, nested functions prior to PHP 5.3 _do not exist_.  Despite looking like they're declared locally, they end up in the global scope.  I think the same is true now, which is why you have to use anonymous functions to achieve any sort of nesting.

Comment: Is there shorthand notation for using all variables like this? C++ has a `[&]` notation (C++'s `[]` is the equivalent to PHP's `use()`) but `use(&)` in PHP doesn't work. In a function with a lot of local variables, it would be nice to be able to write something short instead of `use($foo, $bar, /*lots of other variables*/)`.

Answer (score 10):

You must use the `use` keyword.

```
$bar = function() use(&$l) {
};
$bar();
```

In the very very old PHP 5.2 and earlier this didn't work. The syntax you've got isn't a closure, but a definition of a global function.

```
function foo() { function bar() { } }
```

works the same as:

```
function foo() { include "file_with_function_bar.php"; }
```

If you execute function `foo` twice, PHP will complain that you've tried to re-define a (global) function `bar`.

Comment: Too many pronouns! What will die on second execution? The outer-variable, or the variable as it is `use`'d in the inner function? And what does die mean (not being snarky, just want to know). Does die mean the variable can't be used or that it has to be re-established by some other means? I'm guessing it dies (in whatever sense) because it the shared location they both point at can't be re-pointed at after first execution? What if the variable is made static and then unset right afterward?

Comment: die means `die("Fatal Error")`. There are no closures nor inner functions in PHP <= 5.2 – function inside function is not allowed, and the fact it isn't syntax error is accidental (it should be sytnax error).

PHP 5.3 is entirely different. It allows functions inside functions, but with slightly different syntax. Once you get syntax right, in PHP 5.3+, it will work as you'd expect in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can read default value by:

```
function(){
    return preg_match(
                     "yourVar = \d+"
                   ,  str_file_get_contents(functionFile)
                  ,   arrayToPutFieldsValue
           );
 }
```

If You would use two functons in the same time - it's like someone's using a spoon and You want to take a food from that spoon - You'll waste a food or some of You will starv.
Anyway - You would have to set a pointer somehow in a hard way.
It's impossible to get any field from other function or class without calling it to life.
Functions/methods are instance-like - they need to be called.

Share the common fields by accessing a global fields with synchronized functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function a()
{

    function val1($arg=null)
    {
        static $a;
        if ($arg !== null) $a = $arg;
        else return $a;
    }


    function b()
    {
        val1('1234');
        echo val1() . '<br>';  // shows: 1234
        val1('my custom data');
        echo val1() . '<br>';  // shows: my custom data
    }
    b();


}
a();
```

Used `val1('my custom data')` to set my value

Used `val1()` to get my value