# How to access a variable inside a function declared as a variable?

Tags: php, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to access outer local variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408908/is-it-possible-to-access-outer-local-variable-in-php)
>   [PHP closure scope problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543419/php-closure-scope-problem)

Given this PHP function:

```
function get_deals_by_type($records, $type) {
  $available = function($record) {
    if($record->mobile_type == $type) return $record;
  };
  return array_filter($records, $available);
}
```

... how can I access the passed in `$type` inside of the function declared in `$available`? As it stands right now, `$type` returns `NULL` for `array_filter` regardless of what value is passed in to `get_deals_by_type()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure but:

```
function get_deals_by_type($records, $type) {
  $available = function($record) use ($type) {
    if($record->mobile_type == $type) return $record;
  };
  return array_filter($records, $available);
}
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php (shopping cart example)